# jquery datepicker in div, position is null error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use a datepicker, but I don't need any input field to populate selected date, just grab selected value and use for my needs.

I'm implementing such case: have a div, if user clicks on div datepicker must be shown.

Could not make it work. Last implementation with hidden input field, but it also fails with error "position is null", because control could not get offset of hidden element..

Any ideas for implementation?

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

        $('.datepicker-holder').live('click', function () {
            $('.datepicker').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker('show');
        });

    });

</script>
```

Markup:

```
<div class="datepicker-holder">
    <input class="datepicker" type="hidden"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another try after the OP clarification.
When you click in the div the datepicker is shown, it seems that the position is Ok. Tested in chrome :)

http://jsbin.com/ivuju3/6/

```
  <div>
    asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadsasdasd
  </div>
  <div class="datepicker-holder" style="border: 1px solid red">
    calendar should appear here -> <input class="datepicker" style="width: 0px; border: none;"/>
    click here
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        $('.datepicker-holder').live('click', function () {
            $('.datepicker').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker('show');
        });

    });
  </script>
```

If this doesn't work, you have to use the beforeShow event in datepicker to set the position of the datepicker but I don't think that will work (position is calculated after that event) so only changing jquery-ui source code, will work.

Comment: I've created exactly the same code yesterday :).. Any way, you answer is right.. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

This example opens the datepicker by pressing a button, you can use datepicker examples to instead use an image, I don't know what you really want :) . I tested this and it works in FF, Chrome and IE8:

```
<form>
    <p>Date is here: <input id="date" type="textbox" style="display:none;" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#date").datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonText: "select" });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is not exacty I'm looking for.. I have a <div> if user clicks on div, I need to show calendar. No buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is my implementation:

Code:

```
    $('.plantodate').live('click', function () {
            $(this).after('<span class="datepicker"></span>');
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                onSelect: function (date, inst) {
                    $('.datepicker').remove();
                }
            });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="plantodate"></div>
```

It works great for me.